# rasterio - set nodata value per band

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, nodata, multi-band

I am looking for a way to specify a different `nodata` value for each band of a raster with [`rasterio`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I tried:

- using the `nodata` key in the profile with a tuple or list of nodata values,
- setting the `nodatavals` attribute,

but none of these methods worked.

In case it is possible at all to specify different `nodata` values using `rasterio`, how can it be done?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about rasterio, but you can use [GDAL's gdalwarp function](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) to overwrite the nodata values of each band in a multiband raster by placing the values inside quotes (single on linux, double on windows), for example this will rewrite the values of a five band raster to 0 for band 1, 1 for band 2, and so on:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -dstnodata "0 1 2 3 4" input.tif output.tif
```

However, this will give you warnings each time you use a different value for another band because the geotiff file format does not support different nodata values across the bands, from the [gdal documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html):

"GDAL stores band nodata value in the non standard TIFFTAG_GDAL_NODATA ASCII tag (code 42113) for files created with the default profile GDALGeoTIFF. ***Note that all bands must use the same nodata value***."

So, if you change the output format to another raster file format that can deal with the different nodata values such as GDAL virtual raster, you should be fine, such as:

```
gdalwarp -of VRT -dstnodata "0 1 2 3 4" input.tif output.vrt
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot write different `nodata` values with *rasterio*. From the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html?highlight=nodata#rasterio.io.DatasetWriter.nodata) (emphasis mine):

> `nodata`
>
> The dataset’s **single** nodata value
>
> Notes
>
> May be set.
>
> [...]
>
> `nodatavals`
>
> Nodata values for each band
>
> Notes
>
> **This may not be set.**

I believe this is due to the fact, as pointed out in other answers, that the [GeoTIFF Standard only allows one `nodata` value for all bands](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#nodata-value).